# Configuring Jest to mimic webpack resolve root and resolve alias

Tags: webpack, jestjs

I am working on setting up a project with Webpack & Jest. At the moment Webpack resolve configurations cause complications with Jest tests. In my webpack config I have the following options set:

```
  resolve: {
    root: [__dirname + "/src/" ],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.coffee', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss', '.svg']
  }
```

This lets me require assets and modules with:

```
import UnknownImg from 'assets/unknown';
```

The above actually lives (relative to my project root) `src/assets/unknown.svg`.

However, when I run the test for files with lines like the above I get errors when resolving the path to that required module/asset.

`Error: /Users/byronsm/dev/nerve-center/src/components/organisms/system_status.jsx: Cannot find module 'assets/unknown' from '/Users/byronsm/dev/nerve-center/src/components/organisms'`

In this case it appears to  be doing a relative lookup of the imported module path. Is there a way for me to get Jest to behave the same as Webpack?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A solution is now provided in the official jest docs. See [Webpack Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html).

In short, add the `modulePaths` option to your jest config in`package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "modulePaths": ["src"], 
    ...
}
```

Comment: The link is broken it seems. I think this is what you're referring to: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulepaths-array-string

Comment: @clu, I've updated the link in the answer - hopefully it'll pass peer review 

Comment: Thanks @jolyonruss

Answer (score 4):

You can use Jest 20+ [`resolver` option](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#resolver-string) and plug it with [jest-webpack-resolver](https://github.com/mkg0/jest-webpack-resolver)

This package does not seem mature (several days old) but does the job for me. Also, as of now, it requires Jest config to be in a separate `jest.config.js` file or provided via CLI (does not support `package.json`).

Answer (score 2):

After a good nights rest I looked at this again and realized it wasn't a Jest configuration but node. The best way to mimic the behavior of the resolve.root config in webpack is to set the environment variable `NODE_PATH` to the same directory when running `jest`:

```
NODE_PATH=src jest
```

That doesn't really solve the issue of multiple directories it solved my issue. This article helped me understand the solution a little better https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520.

Answer (score 2):

[Jestpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jestpack) aims to solve this problem by building your test files with Webpack before running them with Jest. This means any special module resolution rules or loaders in your Webpack config will work in the exact same way as your production build.

Comment: Seems like an unfair labeling of "link only" I think their answer is pretty legible without the link itself.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [`mimic-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mimic-webpack) to take a webpack config and hook into node's require in order to resolve paths just like webpack. I haven't tested it with jest, but it should work with any spec runner that runs on node and will even support simple loaders.

Answer (score 1):

Jest version `23.6.0`:

Add this line to `jest.config.js`

```
moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
```

or in `package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src"], 
    ...
}
```