# Testing with Jest and Webpack aliases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs, webpack-2

I am looking to be able to use webpack aliases to resolve imports when using jest, and optimally, reference the `webpack.aliases` to avoid duplication.

Jest conf:

```
  "jest": {
    "modulePaths": ["src"],
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@shared$": "<rootDir>/shared/",
      "^@components$": "<rootDir>/shared/components/"
    }
  },
```

Webpack aliases:

```
exports.aliases = {
    '@shared': path.resolve(paths.APP_DIR, 'shared'),
    '@components': path.resolve(paths.APP_DIR, 'shared/components'),
};
```

Imports:

```
import Ordinal from '@shared/utils/Ordinal.jsx';
import Avatar from '@components/common/Avatar.jsx';
```

For some reason the `@` causes issues, so when removed (in both alias and import), it can find `shared` but `components` still cannot be resolved.

```
 FAIL  src/shared/components/test/Test.spec.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@shared/utils/Ordinal.jsx' from 'Test.jsx'
```

I have tried using [jest-webpack-alias](https://github.com/mwolson/jest-webpack-alias), [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) and the [Jest/Webpack docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html)

Comment: since you use webpack-2 are you using `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` in env:test ? see: [using-with-webpack-2](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html#using-with-webpack-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190795/configuring-jest-to-mimic-webpack-resolve-root-and-resolve-alias

Comment: The `@` symbol indicates a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope), which is typically searched inside your third party packages path.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed.

Below is a working setup:

**Versions**

`"jest": "~20.0.4"`

`"webpack": "^3.5.6"`

**package.json**

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@root(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src$1",
    "^@components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components$1",
  } 
}
```

**webpack.shared.js**

```
const paths = {
  APP_DIR: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src'),
};

exports.resolveRoot = [paths.APP_DIR, 'node_modules'];

exports.aliases = {
  '@root': path.resolve(paths.APP_DIR, ''),
  '@components': path.resolve(paths.APP_DIR, 'components'),
};
```

Comment: As a note, configuration may otherwise be located in `jest.config.js`.

Comment: My question seems is `moduleNameMapper ` just work to your source code, but doesn't work to your package code. How to resolve some packages in node_modules which has `@` or `@@` alias in jest? Such as package `umi`.

Answer (score 63):

Since I had the same problem before I read again, and this time more carefully the documentation.  Correct config should be:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@shared(.*)$": "<rootDir>/shared$1",
      "^@components(.*)$": "<rootDir>/shared/components$1"
    }
  },
```

Comment: I tried implementing this configuration, but still have the same issue. It cannot find the imported file: `Cannot find module '@shared/utils/Ordinal.jsx' from 'Test.jsx'`.

Comment: I had to resolve my path with `"modulePaths": ["src"]`. Then yes, this solution worked: `"^Commons$": "./Commons"`

Comment: I was having the same issue as the OP and @mayid's solution was what finally resolved the issue for me.

Comment: In case you're a total newbie like me, this configuration is found in your ```package.json``` file

Answer (score 46):

For anyone using `@` as the `root` of their modules, you have to be more specific since other libs can use the `@` in node modules.

```
 "jest": {
    moduleNameMapper: {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
 }
```

It translates to "anything that matches `@/` should be sent to `<rootDir>/src/<rest of the path>`

Comment: In addition, this mapping needs to be added in `package.json` file, under `jest` section. probably there is a section in that place already.

Answer (score 44):

Using: `"jest": "^26.5.3",` and `"webpack": "4.41.5",`
I was able to properly match my webpack/typescript aliases in the `jest.config.js` with this pattern:

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
   // the rest of your config
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/app/components'),
        'modules': path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/app/modules'),
        'types': path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/types'),
        'hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/app/hooks'),
        'reducers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/app/reducers'),
        '__test-utils__': path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/app/__test-utils__') 
      }
    },
}
```

Jest.config.js:

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^types/(.*)$':  '<rootDir>/js/types/$1',
    '^components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/js/app/components/$1',
    '^modules/(.*)$':  '<rootDir>/js/app/modules/$1',
    '^hooks/(.*)$':  '<rootDir>/js/app/hooks/$1',
    '^reducers/(.*)$':  '<rootDir>/js/app/reducers/$1',
    '^__test-utils__/(.)$': '<rootDir>/js/app/__test-utils__/$1' 
  }
```

Here's an explanation of the symbols:

- `(.*)$`: capture whatever comes after the exact match (the directory)
- `$1`: map it to this value in the directory I specify.

and tsconfig.json:

```
    "paths": {
      "config": ["config/dev", "config/production"],
      "components/*": ["js/app/components/*"],
      "modules/*": ["js/app/modules/*"],
      "types/*": ["js/types/*"],
      "hooks/*": ["js/app/hooks/*"],
      "reducers/*": ["js/app/reducers/*"],
      "__test-utils__/*": ["js/app/__test-utils__/*"]
    }
```

Comment: If you're confident you did everything right but TS is still complaining about not finding the import: friendly reminder to restart your TS server.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes =)

Comment: It was the dang `$1` for me.

Answer (score 10):

None of the suggested answers worked for me.

Was able to solve it with the following pattern:

Jest version 25+

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^Screens(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/screens/$1',
    '^Components(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
    '^Assets(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/assets/$1',
    '^Services/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/services/$1',
  },
```

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, Try switching the alias order, keep the more specific up and less specific down, e.g.

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^@components$": "<rootDir>/shared/components/",
  "^@shared$": "<rootDir>/shared/"
}
```

Comment: Tried in combination with leo's answer, still have the same errors.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the complete code, github preferably?

Comment: unfortunately not as it's a private corporate repository.

Comment: Could you create a git repo with the minimally viable code where this issue is reproducible?

Comment: I'm also getting the same error message for a scoped package. I've created a very small project at https://gist.github.com/batwicket/da72ffa7d5324d8f7c5eb11f0ba07fad . I tried the alias approach.. no luck. I'm probably missing something simple. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes we have the same issue.
Importing from a location called "@location" and it seems the "@" is causing an issue.

Answer (score 8):

This is a real insanity but when I try to map module in package.json like this:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    '@root/(.*)': '<rootDir>/../$1'
  }
}
```

It doesn't work.

But when I do the same in `jest.config.js` it works:

```
module.exports = {
   moduleNameMapper: {
     '@root/(.*)': '<rootDir>/../$1'
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this solution works well for me:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^Screens(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/screens/$1',
    '^Components(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
    '^Assets(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/assets/$1',
    '^Services/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/services/$1',
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume your webpack aliases lies in webpack.yml in "resolved_paths" block.

To add same aliases in jest, if your jest config is in package.json, use [moduleDirectories](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#moduledirectories-arraystring):

```js
"jest":{
  "moduleDirectories":[
     ".",
      "<rootDir>/shared/components/",
      "<rootDir>/shared/",
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```