# Jest Tests Error - Cannot find module 'expect' from 'jest_expect.js'

Tags: javascript, testing, webpack, jestjs, webpack-dev-server

I followed the guide as per [Jest configuration](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html) for Webpack built React applications & have resolved quite a few errors I had previously. However, this following error has be puzzled. Error:

```
Cannot find module 'expect' from 'jest_expect.js'      
      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:194:17)
```

Here is my package.json

```
   "devDependencies / dependencies" :
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^22.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^22.3.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
    ...
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1"
     },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleDirectories": ["mode_modules"],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "jsx"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "app(.*)$": "<rootDir>/apps$1",
      "appAthenaTrader(.*)$": "<rootDir>/apps/athenaTrader$1",
      "common(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/modules/Common$1",
      "modules(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/modules$1",
      "src(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src$1"
    },
    "modulePaths": ["src", "apps"]
  }
```

My webpack.config.js :

```
const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'apps'),
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  modules: path.join(__dirname, 'src/modules'),
  common: path.join(__dirname, 'src/modules/Common'),
  styles: path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles')
};

const common = {
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      app: PATHS.app,
      Common: PATHS.common,
      modules: PATHS.modules,
      src: PATHS.src,
      styles: PATHS.styles
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [PATHS.app, PATHS.src],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
...
```

The test I have written is:

```
import { Map as iMap } from 'immutable';
import * as actions from '../actionTypes';
import * as actionTypes from '../actions';

describe('Testing of User actions...', () => {
  it('should create an action for sendingUserAuthRequest', () => {
    const action = {
      type: actionTypes.SEND_AUTH_REQUEST,
      payload: iMap({
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: false
      })
    };
    expect(actions.sendUserAuthRequest()).toEqual(action);
  });
});
```

Some of the solutions I have read & tried include [this link to regex moduleNameMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47253895/434697).

To reiterate, whenever I run the tests, I get the

```
Cannot find module 'expect' from 'jest_expect.js'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely the "m" on "mode" typo where it should be "node":

```
"moduleDirectories": ["mode_modules"], // <- Note the typo `mode` vs `node` here
```

Comment: Thanks, that & the regex were the problem.